# How to get image source from featured images of specific category and store in an array

Tags: php, wordpress

My objective is to check all posts to see if they are within a specific category, if they are within that category, I would like to store there image src in an array $backgroundimage[$x]. And then Later use these items in a slider. Currently the code outputs the same image every time.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
            if ( in_category( "Uncategorized" ) ) :
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    for ($x = 0; $x <= 3; $x++) {    

                          $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), full, false);

                          $backgroundimage[$x]=$src[0] ;
                                                } ?>


                <?php } endif; ?>

 <?php endwhile; else :
    _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.', 'textdomain' );
endif; ?>
```

Later I would like to dynamically insert the $backgroundimage[1] along with the rest into some inline css. I am currently getting the same image.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I was eventually able to accomplish the task.

```
<?php $x= 1 ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
            if ( in_category( "Uncategorized" ) ) :
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {


                          $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), full, false);

                          $backgroundimage[$x]=$src[0] ;
                                          $x++;


                }
            endif; ?>

 <?php endwhile; else :
    _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.', 'textdomain' );
endif; ?>
```